# Best approach to a multiplayer game

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm starting to develop multiplayer games in flex/as3. Currently I abuse of `HTTPService` class to make requests to the server in a turn based game. I don't know if it is ok using this component though.

And what if I need to make a massive multiplayer?

Can I have some tips around these matters? Like best approaches, components, etc.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets, although they appear to be the new hammer for all programmers to abuse at the moment it makes total sense to use in multiplayer games, there are many solution out there currently using the TCP protocol though it would be more beneficial to use UDP:

"UDP is really faster than TCP, and the simple reason is because it's non-existent acknowledge packet (ACK) that permits a continuous packet stream, instead of TCP that acknowledges a set of packets, calculatd by using the TCP window size and round-trip time (RTT)."

It is not essential you could still use any of the available TCP ones (although less performant would be 100x more performant than constant HTTP requests) and will leverage many advantages over HTTP (serialization of object {no more nasty XML}).

Comment: I was under the impression that WebSockets were a browser feature; and had nothing to do with the Flash Player.  As such, I'm not sure how this answer relates to the actual question.  Trying to make use of WebSockets inside of a Flash Application seems like it would be incredibly difficult; especially when Flash Player has it's own socket implementation which would work a lot more browsers w/ much more consistency.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com WebSockets is a protocol. Here is an AS3 project that uses the protocol https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket and here are the specs for WebSockets protocol http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Comment: @The_asMan Thanks for the education.  This is a relevant quote from Wikipedia that I missed the first time around "WebSocket is designed to be implemented in web browsers and web servers, but it can be used by any client or server application." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Comment: Kaazing (http://kaazing.com/products/html5-edition) has a decent gateway to create websockets between Flex/Flash and Java. Flex has a decent implementation of Websocket protocol for anyone needing a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Flash [Remoting](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/),  and [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-server-family.html) (or [similiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190802/alternatives-to-flash-media-server-for-multiplayer-game-development)) for more efficient communication to a server.